# Hangout link not created in service account google calendar api php

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I'm not able to generate meet link from GSUIT service account for the google calendar api from the following code. I am getting this error when i run this function

Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "invalid", "message": "Invalid conference type value." } ], "code": 400, "message": "Invalid conference type value." } } in D:\xampp\htdocs\projects\serviceaccount\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Http\REST.php:128 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\projects\serviceaccount\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Http\REST.php(103): Google\Http\REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google\Service\...') #1 [internal function]: Google\Http\REST::doExecute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google\Service\...') #2 D:\xampp\htdocs\projects\serviceaccount\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Task\Runner.php(182): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #3 D:\xampp\htdocs\projects\serviceaccount\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Http\REST.php(66): Google\Task\Runner->run() #4 D:\xampp\htdocs\projects\serviceaccount\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Client.php in D:\xampp\htdocs\projects\serviceaccount\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Http\REST.php on line 128

Code:

```
<pre>
$client = new Google\Client();
$client->setAuthConfig($jsonKey);
$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.audit.readonly']);

$client->setSubject('myserviceemail@gserviceaccount.com');

$client->setAccessType('offline');

$cal_id = 'myemail@gsuit.com';

$calendarService = new Google\Service\Calendar($client);

$event = new Google\Service\Calendar\Event(array(
  'summary' => 'test link generate', //'Google Calendar ',
  'description' => 'Book Room', //'Book Room',
  'start' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2021-07-17T00:50:00+05:30',//'2018-08-16T14:30:00-00:00',
    'timeZone' => 'Asia/Kolkata',
  ),
  'end' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2021-07-17T00:55:00+05:30',//'2018-08-16T14:30:00-01:00',
    'timeZone' => 'Asia/Kolkata',
  ),
  'reminders' => array(
    'useDefault' => FALSE,
    'overrides' => array(
      array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
    ),
  ),
  'conferenceData' => array(
    'createRequest' => array(
      'conferenceSolutionKey' => array(
        'type' => 'hangoutsMeet'
      ),
        'requestId' => 'ADGGSH'. time()
    )
    )   
));

$createdEvent = $calendarService->events->insert($cal_id, $event, array('conferenceDataVersion' => 1)); 
</pre>
```

I'm getting following error with this code, But without adding (ConferenceData property and setting conferenceDataVersion = 1) i'm able to  create event without the hangout link

Resource:

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client
composer require google/apiclient:^2.10

Answer (score 0):

If you will check [Google Calendar API PHP reference documentation](http://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/php/latest/index.html), [Google_Service_Calendar_Events_Resource insert()](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Calendar_Events_Resource.html) expects an [Google_Service_Calendar_Event](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Calendar_Event.html) object. Where the `conferenceData` should be a [Google_Service_Calendar_ConferenceData](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Calendar_ConferenceData.html).

### Sample Code:

```
$conference = new \Google_Service_Calendar_ConferenceData();
$conferenceRequest = new \Google_Service_Calendar_CreateConferenceRequest();
$conferenceSolutionKey = new \Google_Service_Calendar_ConferenceSolutionKey();
$conferenceSolutionKey->setType("hangoutsMeet");
$conferenceRequest->setRequestId('ADGGSH'. time());
$conferenceRequest->setConferenceSolutionKey($conferenceSolutionKey);
$conference->setCreateRequest($conferenceRequest);

$event->setConferenceData($conference);
```

or

```
$event = new Google\Service\Calendar\Event(array(

  ......

  'conferenceData' => $conference   
));
```

Comment: I tried the way you told me to do it.....I had already passed these parameters before in the array. The problem here is if i set (conferenceDataVersion = 1) parameter  i'm getting this fatal error....If i dont set it event is created without meet link

Comment: I didn't get what you mean. In your initial code, you passed an array object in your `conferenceData` which caused the fatal error `Invalid conference type value`. And now you mean even when trying the solution provided where passing a `ConferenceData` object you still encountered the same fatal error?. Could you provide the updated code that you used when you implement the proposed solution?

Comment: Can you also confirm if you are trying to impersonate a user using service account? or impersonating a service account using a service account? `$client->setSubject('myserviceemail@gserviceaccount.com');` because this code is used for impersonation and the email you are trying to impersonate seems to be a service account.  You can refer here on [how to authenticate with service account](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#authentication-with-service-accounts)

Comment: You need to impersonate a workspace user to be able to create a google meet invite since service account don't have such privilege

Comment: By the way, i noticed a typo in the answer provided. I changed `$conferenceRequest->setConferenceSolutionKey(conferenceSolutionKey);` to `$conferenceRequest->setConferenceSolutionKey($conferenceSolutionKey);`. I already updated the answer. Again, Please provide your latest code and the error encountered and please check the user impersonated by the service account

Comment: Below is my updated code.....The event is created but without any hangout link when i insert the event like this `$createdEvent = $calendarService->events->insert($cal_id, $event);`

Comment: But when i insert the event like this `$createdEvent = $calendarService->events->insert($cal_id, $event, array('conferenceDataVersion' => 1));` ...im getting the fatal error

Comment: Yes i'm impersonate a user using service account

Comment: I think your impersonation is incorrect. It should be `$client->setSubject('mypersonalemail@gsuit.com');`

Comment: ok. what would be my $cal_id = ? ....`$cal_id = 'mypersonalemail@gsuit.com';` or `$cal_id = 'clientemail@gserviceaccount.com';`

Comment: still $cal_id = 'mypersonalemail@gsuit.com'

Comment: getting this now .....Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: { "error": "unauthorized_client", "error_description": "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested." }

Comment: have you successfully  delegated domain-wide access to the service account ?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation

Answer (score 0):

```
$client = new Google\Client();
$client->setAuthConfig($jsonKey);
$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.audit.readonly']);

$client->setSubject('clientemail@gserviceaccount.com'); //This is my GSUIT service account(client email) created which is impersonating(linked to my personal GSUIT email)

$client->setAccessType('offline');

$cal_id = 'mypersonalemail@gsuit.com'; //The events created will appear on my GSUIT personal account

$calendarService = new Google\Service\Calendar($client);

$conference = new Google\Service\Calendar\ConferenceData();
 $conferenceRequest = new Google\Service\Calendar\CreateConferenceRequest();
 $conferenceSolutionKey = new Google\Service\Calendar\ConferenceSolutionKey();
 $conferenceSolutionKey->setType("hangoutsMeet");
 $conferenceRequest->setRequestId('ADGGSH'. time());
 $conferenceRequest->setConferenceSolutionKey($conferenceSolutionKey);
 $conference->setCreateRequest($conferenceRequest);

$event = new Google\Service\Calendar\Event(array(

  ......

  'conferenceData' => $conference   
));

$createdEvent = $calendarService->events->insert($cal_id, $event, array('conferenceDataVersion' => 1));
```

Error :

Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "invalid", "message": "Invalid conference type value." } ], "code": 400, "message": "Invalid conference type value." } }